# Saving data from a file to a struct in c

Tags: c, string, pointers, data-structures, struct

I have two structs that I have to fill with student data. The data is in the format:

age, name, grade, age, group, turn

and in the header of the file is the number of student in the data.

```c
struct school //school
{
    char group; //A,B,C,D,E,F
    char turn; //Morning, AFTERNOON
};

struct student
{
    char *name; 
    char *grade;
    int age;
    struct school *E;
}student[6];
```

I tried to save first the data from a text with only the age, name, and grade to see if I could do it:

```c
void get_file(const char* file, int *n){ //n is the amount of students
    FILE* fptr;

    fptr = fopen(file, "r");
    if (fptr == NULL){
        printf( "\n Error \n");
        exit(1);
    }
    char* temp;
    int tam = 0;
    fscanf(fptr, "%d", n); //size of the list of students 
    for(int i= 0; i < *n; i++){

        fscanf(fptr, "%d,%s,%s", &student.age[i],temp, student[i].grade);
        tam = strlen(temp);
        student[i].name = (char*)malloc(tam * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(student[i].name, temp);
        printf("%s\n", student[i].name);//to see if it's correct the content
    } 
    fclose(fptr);
}
```

But, `student.name` store for example `"Josh, A+"` when it should only be `"Josh"`. How can I fix this?

It's for an assignment.

EDIT:
My data looks like this

```
4 //size of list
Josh,A,20,D,M
Amber,B,23,E,M
Kevin,C,22,D,A
Adam,A+,21,C,A
```

Using the Remy Lebeau's solution, I got this

```
void get_file(const char* file, int *n){
    *n = 0;

    FILE* fptr = fopen(file, "r");
    if (fptr == NULL){
        printf( "\n Error \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    char name[80];
    char grade[2];

    fscanf(fptr, "%d", n); //size of the list of students 

    for(int i = 0; i < *n; i++){
        fscanf(fptr, "%80[^,],%2[^,],%d,%c,%c", &student[i].age, name, grade,&student[i].group, &student[i].turn);
        student[i].name = strdup(name);
        student[i].grade = strdup(grade);
    } 

    fclose(fptr);
}
```

But I got a problem, because I made this change

```
struct student
{
    char *name; 
    char *grade;
    int age;
    struct school E; //it was struct school *E
}student[6];
```

to pass the information, but my Teacher said that I couldn't change it, so how can I load information in `struct school *E`?

Comment: After an answer has been posted, please don't change your question by applying the corrections recommended in the answer, because that invalidates the answer.

Comment: Moving data from a file into memory is usually called loading, not saving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your call to `fscanf()`:

- `&student.age[i]` needs to be `&student[i].age`.
- `temp` and `student::grade` are uninitialized pointers, they don't point anywhere, so reading data to memory pointed by them is *undefined behavior*. `fscanf()` will not allocate memory for you, you need to pre-allocate `char[]` buffers yourself for `fscanf()` to then read into.
- `%s` reads non-whitespace characters *including* `','`, which is why your code is not stopping on the `,` following `Josh`. Try using `%[^,]` instead of `%s` for that field.

Try something more like this:

```c
void get_file(const char* file, int *n){
    *n = 0;

    FILE* fptr = fopen(file, "r");
    if (fptr == NULL){
        printf( "\n Error \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    char name[256];
    char grade[5];

    fscanf(fptr, "%d", n); //size of the list of students 

    for(int i = 0; i < *n; i++){
        fscanf(fptr, "%d,%255[^,],%4s", &student[i].age, name, grade);
        student[i].name = strdup(name);
        student[i].grade = strdup(grade);
        printf("%d %s %s\n", student[i].age, student[i].name, student[i].grade);
    } 

    fclose(fptr);
}
```

**UPDATE**:

The file data you have now shown does not match the format you described, which your code is expecting. You described (and coded) the file data as:

`age, name, grade, age, group, turn` (why 2 ages?)

But what you have shown looks more like:

`name, grade, age, group, turn`

You changed your format string in `fscanf()` to this new format, but you didn't change the order of the variables being read into to match this format. So, you are reading the `name` value into your `age` field, the `grade` value into the `name` field, and the `age` value into the `grade` field.

Also, you are not even attempting to handle `group` and `turn` correctly. They reside in a completely different structure, which you are not allocating any memory for. You need to allocate a `school` object, read `group` and `turn` into it, and then assign it to `student[i].E`.

With that said, try something more like this:

```c
struct school
{
    char group; //A,B,C,D,E,F
    char turn; //Morning, AFTERNOON
} school[6];

struct student
{
    char *name; 
    char *grade;
    int age;
    struct school *E;
}student[6];

void get_file(const char* file, int *n){
    *n = 0;

    FILE* fptr = fopen(file, "r");
    if (fptr == NULL){
        printf( "\n Error \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    char name[81];
    char grade[3];

    fscanf(fptr, "%d", n); //size of the list of students 

    for(int i = 0; i < *n; i++){
        student[i].E = &school[i]; // or, use malloc() instead, if needed...
        fscanf(fptr, " %80[^,],%2[^,],%d,%c,%c", name, grade, &(student[i].age), &(student[i].E->group), &(student[i].E->turn));
        student[i].name = strdup(name);
        student[i].grade = strdup(grade);
    } 

    fclose(fptr);
}
```

Comment: I tried, and it only prints the first name in the list

Comment: One issue is that your code is not trying to read all of the data in the file. After reading only a portion of the 1st student's data, there is more data left behind. So, when your loop tries to read the 2nd student, it actually reads that left-over data from the 1st student. If you are not going to read all of a student's data, I suggest you use `getline()` or similar function to read an entire student at a time, and then you can parse out the values you need using `sscanf()`.

Comment: I did the same for ```student[i].grade```:  I made another variable like ```temp```  to store

Comment: Good point, I missed that.  I have updated my answer to account for that. In any case, it is really hard to diagnose your problems when you haven't shown what the file data actually looks like. Don't *describe* the data, *show* the data.

Comment: I would like to store all the data in the file, the function that I made is a efficient way to do it? I dind't hav another idea to store the information in the pointer ``` name ```

Comment: "*the function that I made is a efficient way to do it?*" - not particularly, no.  I'm sure there are better ways to handle this.  But again, it is really hard to help you further without seeing the *actual* file data.

Comment: Remy Lebeau, sorry for the delay,  when I was doing the edit  the site went to maintenance,I already added the information, thanks

Comment: @Mari I have updated my answer